# Nilpotent endomorphism - Verification and Intuition

Tags: linear-algebra

For a finite dimensional Vectorspace V and a nilpotent Endomorphism $ \phi$ with index of nilpotency k .
The following is supposed to be an approach to show that parts of the Image of $ \phi^j$ (j<k) must be in the kernel of $ \phi$.

> Suppose this is not the case. Then $\forall x \in Im(\phi^j): \phi(x) \neq 0  \iff   \phi^{j+1}(x) =  \phi(\phi^{j}(x)) \neq 0   $, and $\phi^{j+2}(x) =  \phi(\phi(\phi^{j}(x))) \neq 0 $ by knowing that $Im(\phi^{j})$ is an $\phi$ invariant subspace ( which implies $\implies \phi(\phi^{j}(x)) \in Im(\phi^{j}) \notin Ker(\phi) $ by assumption). Hence repeating this one gets $ \phi^{k}(x) \neq 0 $ which is a contradiction.

Could someone provide a opinion on this, and maybe an alternative more intuitive approach to why this must be true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really follow your proof, especially the reasoning with $\phi^{j+2}$.
You should make explicit why the invariance of $\operatorname{Im}(\phi^j)$ is important and avoid symbols like $\Leftrightarrow$ where English sentences would be clearer and easier to follow.

An alternative argument based on similar ideas would be: since $\phi$ has index of nilpotency $k$, there must be a non-zero vector $v = \phi^{k-1}(u)$ such that $\phi(v) = \phi^k(u) = 0$.
That is, $v \in \operatorname{Im}(\phi^{k-1}) \cap \ker(\phi)$.

But also notice that, for $j < k$,
$$
\phi^{k-1}(V)
= \phi^{j}(\phi^{k - j - 1}(V))
\subseteq \phi^j(V),
$$
from which we conclude that $v \in \phi^j(V) \cap \ker(\phi)$ and in particular that that subspace is non-trivial.